# Change text based on check box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change the text value based on if a check box current value, is checked or is it not checked should state the value of the viewable text to the user. Here is what I have I think I'm close but it wont work.

```
<html>
<body>   

 <style type="text/css">
    .red{ display: none;}
    .blue{ display: none;}
</style>

<script>
// Toggle Text
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".Color").toggle();
            }else($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".Color").toggle();
            }

        });
    });

</script>

     <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="Color"></label>
        </div>

    <div class="red">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong></div>
    <div class="blue">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would the value change to either "red" or "blue"?

Comment: When jQuery runs to get the attr("value") it gets "color"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly but I modified your example code/html slightly. I assumed you wanted to link the showing/hiding of each div depending on when certain checkboxes are ticked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $("." + $(this).val()).show();
            }
            else{
                $("." + $(this).val()).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/whhvks0u/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked"))
                {
                alert("checked");
                }
                else{
                alert("Un-checked");
                }
                if($(this).val()=="red"){
                    //$(".Color").toggle();
                }
                else if($(this).val()=="blue"){
                    //$(".Color").toggle();
                }

            });
        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mjh2rx4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.' + $(this).val()).toggle();
  }
});
```

This is assuming your `input` value is the same as one of your `div` class names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .red    { display: none;}
        .blue   { display: none;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

                $(".color").each(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    var color = $(this).attr("value");
                    $("."+color).show();
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue
    </div>
    <div class="color red">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong></div>
    <div class="color blue">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```